# Missing cost for specific pearl of power

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

So I was rereading the [Pearl of power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/pearl-of-power) description when I came across the last paragraph:

> Different pearls exist for recalling one spell per day of each level
>   from 1st through 9th and for the recall of two spells per day (each of
>   a different level, 6th or lower).

By my understanding, this paragraphs describes two different pearls of power. One that restores one of each slot from 1st to 9th level and another that restores two spells of 6th or lower, effectively working as two 6th pearls of power in one.

The problem is that there is no cost listed for the first pearl, the one that restores one spell of each level. Am I just misreading the pearl of power entry or is it really just not detailed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **Price** line states prices for 1st-9th level Pearls, plus a pearl for restoring two spells (in [d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/pearl-of-power) and the [prd](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/wondrousItems.html#pearl-of-power)):

> Price 1,000 gp (1st), 4,000 gp (2nd), 9,000 gp (3rd), 16,000 gp (4th), 25,000 gp (5th), 36,000 gp (6th), 49,000 gp (7th), 64,000 gp (8th), 81,000 gp (9th), **70,000 gp (two spells)**

The crafting cost line repeats this pattern:

> Cost 500 gp (1st), 2,000 gp (2nd), 4,500 gp (3rd), 8,000 gp (4th), 12,500 gp (5th), 18,000 gp (6th), 24,500 gp (7th), 32,000 gp (8th), 40,500 gp (9th), **35,000 gp (two spells)**

That suggests the first pearl is *nine* such pearls: one for each of the levels you might want to refresh, and purchased for 1,000gp through to 81,000gp (i.e. 1,000 × level²).

The second pearl is just one pearl, which refreshes from among 6th level and below, and is purchased for 70,000gp.

(This wasn't very clearly expressed in that passage.)